# API/Web Service Creation Basics

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, api, soap

I've been handed some documentation about an API and been told to integrate it (the API uses SOAP).  I'm familiar with web services and how they work, but I've never built a functional one.  That is to say, I can create a basic web method in C# but I've never written anything to connect to an external system.

I've read parts of books and I've not been able to find a good example about how to connect to and use a third-party API.  I guess my question would be "how can I use this API with our systems?"  Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just pointing me to some good tutorials.

Comment: What api.  What are you attempting to do with it.

Comment: Generally speaking API's usually come with documentation that includes sample code on how to connect.

Comment: @rerun - It's a proprietary API.  @Chris - Yes the API does include sample SOAP/XML code but I have no idea how to integrate it with ASP.NET/C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty good place to start for [ASP.NET web services](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34279-introduction-to-web-services-in-c%23/).

If you're using .NET 3.0 or higher, I suggest using WCF. If you decide to go that route, I highly suggest [this book.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494)

Here's a breakdown of [Comparing ASP.NET Web Services to WCF Based on Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx).

Hope that helps to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can just add a Web Reference to the API ('Add Service Reference' or 'Add Web Reference' depending on your version of Studio).

From there Studio will download the information it needs to build a proxy class which you can reference and use just like any object in your system.

```
var RemoteService = new RemoteAPI.APIMethods();
var result = RemoteService.Method1(foo, bar);
```